# WooCommerce - Show product category image on single product page template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I seem to be struggling with something in woocommerce.

I have created a single product page template which currently shows the product's featured image at the top of the page in the banner.

However, instead of the product featured image, I would like the banner to display the product category image of the category the product belongs to.

They will only ever belong to one category, so having a fallback isn't that important (I think?!)

To get the product thumbnail I'm using this:

```
<?php 
    $image = get_field('product_single_image', 'options');

    if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">

<?php endif; ?>
```

So it looks like I could use the same code but replace the `product_single_image` with `get_category_thumbnail` or something...

But I think I need to find the category first? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get current category ID on single product page and image

```
global $wp_query;
$terms_post = get_the_terms( $post->cat_ID , 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms_post as $term_cat) { 
    $term_cat_id = $term_cat->term_id; 
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
     echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '">';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Firefog, I can't seem to get this to work - the global bit of code at the top seems to output the Category ID but then the lines of code below don't seem to echo anything out and it's just printing <img src> Is there a way to combine the two so it gets the category ID and then uses that ID to get the image from the category?

Comment: Thanks so much, Firefog. I'm not sure this is working for me but I think it's because of the way I'm implementing it (I'm integrating with Elementor page builder so I found a different workaround). I'll mark it as correct because I believe it to be the correct way to do as I asked :)